# How can I access my own deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Some of my questions have been deleted automatically (roomba), but I put some effort into them that I want to preserve elsewhere. So, how can I access my own deleted questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the links to the deleted questions, you can always access them. You just have to preserve the links. You can still get the links of recently deleted questions (< 60 days) from your profile:

1. Access your profile page
2. Open the *Activity* tab
3. In the *Questions* section, click on *View all X questions*
4. At the bottom, click on *Deleted questions*

Or use this [shortcut](https://serverfault.com/users/deleted-questions/current).

If you don't find them there anymore, you still might have a chance through websites that duplicate the content of the SE forums. Use a search engine to look for them.

Sources for further reading:

- [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/733829)
- [What is the 'deleted recent questions' page in the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/733829)